# REGEX multiline Python missing lines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find and return a pattern of text across multiple lines in a file.
I have tried reading the file in as a single string and as lines e.g., readlines()
The file I read in is this:

```
RECT: 1
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext

text
MMMM
===================

RECT: 2
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext

text
MMMM
===================

RECT: 3
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext

text
MMMM
===================
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
[RECT: 1
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext

text
MMMM
===================,

RECT: 2
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext

text
MMMM
===================,

RECT: 3
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext

text
MMMM
===================]
```

My code:

```
import re
file = open(text)
lines = read.file()

seg = re.findall(r"\bRECT\b.+(?:\n.+)+", lines)
```

what I get though is this:

```
[RECT: 1
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext,
RECT: 2
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext,
RECT: 3
texttextetxt
text
texttexttexttext]
```

Any help searching and returning all the way to the line of ========'s?
Python 3.6.1

Comment: Using `.+` prevents matching the empty lines, but using `\bRECT\b.+(?:\n.*)+` just matches the rest of all the lines without any `===================` logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```php
^RECT:.*(?:\n(?!RECT:|=+$).*)*\n=+$\s*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `RECT:.*` Match `RECT:` and the rest of the line
- `(?:\n(?!RECT:|=+$).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with either `RECT:` or only equals signs
- `\n` Match a newline
- `=+$` Match 1+ times `=` and assert end of the string
- `\s*` Match trailing whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9iaK1r/1)

Example code

```
from pprint import pprint
import re

pattern = r"^RECT:.*(?:\n(?!RECT:|=+$).*)*\n=+$\s*"

s = ("RECT: 1\n"
     "texttextetxt\n"
     "text\n"
     "texttexttexttext\n\n"
     "text\n"
     "MMMM\n"
     "===================\n\n"
     "RECT: 2\n"
     "texttextetxt\n"
     "text\n"
     "texttexttexttext\n\n"
     "text\n"
     "MMMM\n"
     "===================\n\n"
     "RECT: 3\n"
     "texttextetxt\n"
     "text\n"
     "texttexttexttext\n\n"
     "text\n"
     "MMMM\n"
     "===================")

pprint(re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['RECT: 1\n'
 'texttextetxt\n'
 'text\n'
 'texttexttexttext\n'
 '\n'
 'text\n'
 'MMMM\n'
 '===================\n'
 '\n',
 'RECT: 2\n'
 'texttextetxt\n'
 'text\n'
 'texttexttexttext\n'
 '\n'
 'text\n'
 'MMMM\n'
 '===================\n'
 '\n',
 'RECT: 3\n'
 'texttextetxt\n'
 'text\n'
 'texttexttexttext\n'
 '\n'
 'text\n'
 'MMMM\n'
 '===================']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
/RECT[a-zA-Z: \s0-9]+(=){19}/
```